# How can I set container content with a .qml page?

Tags: qt, blackberry, qml, blackberry-10

I'm devolopping a Blackberry 10 mobile application using the BB Native SDK.

All I want is to set a dynamic **'Container'** which is a part of a specific (.qml) page like below (**main.qml**), that will be filled by choice with differents qml pages from assets (for example like "**content1.qml**")

Is that possible ? if so, how I can do that ?

---

**main.qml :**

```
import bb.cascades 1.2

Page {
    Container {
        layout: DockLayout {}
        //Todo: fill me with QML
      Header {
          title: "Hello Boys  ;)"
          horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Fill
          verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Top
      }

       Container {
         id: selectedCont
         objectName: "selectedContObj"
       }

       Footer {
           title: "Hi Girls  ;)"
           horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Fill
           verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Bottom
       }

    }
}
```

**content1.qml** :

```
Container {
    Label{
        text: "Hello World"
    }
    Button {
        text: "Submit"
    }
    Button {
        text: "Cancel"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to give your Container in content1.qml an id, let's say **id: container1**.

Since a Container is a Control (Container inherits from Control), you can simply add container1 to selectedCont:

```
selectedCont.removeAll();
selectedCont.add(content1.container1);
```

You can also use replace if you already have a container in selectedCont:

```
selectedCont.replace(0, content1.container1);
```

This assumes that main.qml and content1.qml are in the same folder.

If you want to achieve the same from C++, you need to load the qml file using:

```
QmlDocument *qml1 = QmlDocument::create("asset:///container1.qml").parent(this);
Container* container1 = qml1->createRootObject<Container>();
```

To get a pointer to your selectContObj you can do:

```
QmlDocument *qml = QmlDocument::create("asset:///main.qml").parent(this);
AbstractPane *root = qml->createRootObject<AbstractPane>();
Container* selectCont = root->findChild<bb::cascades::Container*>("selectContObj");
```

Comment: Thx !! But can you explain more ? I want to do it with C++ .

Comment: I added C++ to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a ControlDelegate.  These are designed to replace content with qml files.

```
Container {
    layout: DockLayout {}

  Header {
      title: "Hello Boys  ;)"
      horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Fill
      verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Top
  }

   ControlDelegate {
        id: selectedContDelegate
    }

   Footer {
       title: "Hi Girls  ;)"
       horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Fill
       verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Bottom
   }

}
```

Then in your button or wherever you want to change it you do this:

```
selectedContDelegate.source = "Content1.qml"
```

Comment: thx ! But how to use it in C++ ? I can not find the reference of the library that contain the "ControlDelegate" component -> I try this one "bb::cascades::ControlDelegate" like mentionned in this [link](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__cascades__qmlcontroldelegate.html#overview) but he still can not find it

Comment: I'm afraid I've only used the QML way of doing it.  I can't find any examples of using it in c++.  Make sure you have the latest 10.2 version of the SDK.  If you are using 10.1 or older it might not support the controlDelegate.